# How to add <TableRow> between in for loop and Object.key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

<TableBody>

```
{(() => { 
        var result = []; 
        let key = Object.keys(genericResultList)[1]; 
        var list = genericResultList[key]; 
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {    
      ***\<!-- Add in the \<TableRow\> --\>***

        Object.keys(list\[i\]).forEach(key =\> {
        var val = list\[i\]\[key\];
            if (key != 'EDITED' && key != 'CHECKED' && key != 'DELETED' ) {
                result.push(
                    \<TableCell\>{val}\</TableCell\>
                );
            }
        });

    ***\<!-- End of the \<TableRow\> --\>***

    }
    return (result);
})()}
```

</TableBody>

How can i add the TableRow in between the for loop and Object.key

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this ,

```
import { TableRow } from '@material-ui/core';

function MyTable(props) {
  const { data } = props;

  const rows = Object.keys(data).map((key) => (
 <TableRow key={key}>
  <TableCell>{key}</TableCell>
  <TableCell>{data[key]}</TableCell>
 </TableRow>
));

return (
<Table>
  <TableBody>{rows}</TableBody>
</Table>
);
}
```